holding shift to toggle the mouse buttons in lua?
I'm a completely noob at Lua. I've been playing around with it in g-hub for a Logitech mouse and I figured out how to make it notice if shift is held down while the script is run, but I'm pretty far off from figuring out how to make holding shift change the buttons on the mouse to different values. Lik eI want mouse button 4 to go from "mouse button 4" to "1." Any help would be greatly appreciated
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) and IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
        PressKey("2")
        OutputLogMessage("Held")
    end
       if not IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
        OutputLogMessage("NOT Held")
    end
  end



I want mouse button 4 to go from "mouse button 4" to "1."

This would require removing default action from MB4 (on the big picture of mouse in GHub GUI) and handling of all its press/release events in the code.
local with_shift
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
      with_shift = IsModifierPressed("lshift")
      if with_shift then
         PressKey("1")
         OutputLogMessage("Held\n")
      else
         PressMouseButton(4)
         OutputLogMessage("NOT Held\n")
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 4 then
      if with_shift then
         ReleaseKey("1")
      else
         ReleaseMouseButton(4)
      end
   end
end

